# How to block Spotify with Windows Firewall?

Tags: firewall, windows-firewall

How can I block Spotify from accessing the internet with my Windows Firewall? (I use Windows 8. It has the same design as Windows 7.)

I've tried adding an outbound rule to block %APPDATA%\Roaming\Spotify\spotify.exe. I've tried blocking the helper file in the same dir. I've also tried disabling the inbound rules that were allowing Spotify...

Comment: I'm not experienced with Windows Firewall...

Comment: why not uninstall spotify? Here is a free outbound firewall...http://www.sphinx-soft.com/Vista/order.html

Comment: @Moab I want to block Spotify in order to force it offline so that I can listen to music on multiple computers at once.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To solve this, you need one of two options:

- Use %APPDATA%\Roaming\Spotify\Spotify.exe OR
- Use C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Spotify\Spotify.exe

As well, you might want to block the SpotifyWebHelper.exe application for incoming traffic which might be also used for P2P.

Comment: Is there a way to do this for the Spotify Windows 10 app?