# Can I cheat a Windows store app that the Internet is unreachable?

Tags: windows, windows-store-app

I have a Windows store app which will connect to Windows store to check the license when opening. However, the checking proccess makes the application need longer time to initialize.

I have read [How can I block internet access to Spotify's Windows 10 app (on the Windows Store)?](https://superuser.com/questions/1335442/how-can-i-block-internet-access-to-spotifys-windows-10-app-on-the-windows-stor). That solution is not work in my case. If I block my application, it will try to connect to the Windows store forever!

Turning my laptop to the flight mode makes the application open quicklier. Is it possiable to cheat that Windows store app that the Internet is unreachable?

Comment: You should be able to block it via the Windows Firewall.

Comment: @Albin Yes, I'm able to block it via the Windows Firewall(WF). But the behaviour of the application after blocked by WF is different from the behaviour when I turn my laptop to the flight mode. It takes longer time after I block it via WF.

Comment: **Seems** the app checks if there is any network connection and tries to connect when it found one. To make the app think there is no connection you can run it in a virtual environment (e.g. VMware player) without active network adapters.What happens if you have a network connection but not internet, does it take "long" as well?

Comment: I have to do some research to run a Windows Store app in a VM.